# .Net MVC verify only one checkox checked

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a model called `Employee` with a boolean field called OnDuty. Our business rules only allow for one employee on duty.

On the `index` page, I've setup the checkbox so they trigger an update call to update the employee as being "on call". However, I'm not set any other employees to `off duty` using my controller action below. How do I go about making sure that no other employee is on duty?

```cs
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Update(Employee employee)
{
    IEnumerable<Employee> onCallEmployee = _db.Employees.Where(e => e.OnCall == true);
    foreach (Employee e in onCallEmployee) {
        e.OnCall = false;
        _db.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
    _db.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return Json("Employee updated!");
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem here. Is your code not setting other employees.oncall to false? Is the binder not binding the posted employee.oncall to true? What are you having an issue with. P.S. you might want to call SaveChanges() only at the bottom not within the foreach loop and at the bottom.

Comment: Correct, I was unable to save the all the employees. I was able to resolve the issue(s) using the code update in the answer I posted below. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that my error(s) were caused by the way I was trying to update the employees. I had to exclude the employee which was already being updated by the function from `onCallEmployee` because it would throw an error (`Attaching an entity of type 'Employee' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value.`) when trying to save the updates.

Also, based on @mwwallace8, suggestion, I removed the `SaveChanges()` call from the for loop and left a single call at the end.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Update(Employee employee)
{
    IEnumerable<Employee> onCallEmployee = _db.Employees.Where(e => e.OnCall == true && e.ID != employee.ID);
    foreach (Employee e in onCallEmployee) {
        e.OnCall = false;
        _db.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    _db.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return Json("Employee updated!");
}
```